# Overlaying FEA on video stream

Tags: opencv, finite-element-analysis, camera-overlay

I got a video stream from a camera. I would like to overlay an FEA like 3D of one object that showing the stresses on the object dynamically changes.
Do you guys have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Your question needs more focus. Please add any code you have tried. You can surely open your video stream from the camera and display it, so add that code. Share a frame of video and the stress frame/data you want to overlay. Is your question about grabbing the camera feed? Or calculating the stress? Or aligning the overlay with the video? Or pasting the stress overlay? Or displaying the result? Are you using C++ or Python?

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm using Python and I know how to overlay one video stream on other. I searched for FEA simulator which publish a stream so I can overlay it but couldn't find one. The only solution i found generate an pyplot which opens a new window and it cannot be overlayed on video stream.

Comment: I think what you should do is to first convert your 2d video into 3d objects, then when you found 3d geometry, you can mesh it (break into smaller tetrahedral pieces - named elements) . A finite element model surely have two properties: 1- exact and known geometry dimensions, 2- known material properties (like steel, or aluminum